# How to check if client can connect via port 843?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Using socket.io, **port 843** seems to give the least issue with firewalls and such, since flash uses that port.

However, many networks block **port 843**, so they can't connect at all.

I have a load balancer set up that can redirect http traffic from **port 80** to **843** so those such people, but my issue is that I can't think of how to test whether someone has port **843** blocked or not.

Any ideas?

Or if I could change socket.io's **XHR** method to always use an alternate connection url, that would probably be the most ideal. I'm more weary of doing any sort of test that has a timeout, because that delays the connection more. It'd be ideal to change something after the websocket connection attempt times out.

What I'm thinking is..

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:843', {'connect timeout':5000}); 

socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
    // change socket to connect to port 80
}
```

but I'm not sure how I'd change the connect url at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but wouldn't re-initialize socket to port 80 work?

```
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:843', {'connect timeout':5000}); 

socket.on('connect_failed', function(){
    // change socket to connect to port 80
    socket = io.connect('http://example.com:80', {'connect timeout':5000});
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up trying.  I can't tell how well it's actually working at the moment. Some are still saying there are problems.  Also, for some people, the port 80 method, maybe because it's going through a load balancer and is XHR polling, disconnects a lot.  It would be ideal to have it always connect to :843 for websockets and :80 for xhr.

Comment: @sadtaco you have to test it locally to see weather it's working or not. Try to replicate your production setup with virtual boxes... it's the only way you'll actually be able to test, debug and deploy A grade software...